# Priority queue ordering of elements

Tags: java, scjp

How come the elements of priority queue are ordered according to natural order by default as it doesn't implement comparable interface?

From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html), it says elements are ordered based on natural ordering, but I can't find anywhere it talks about an equals method nor comparable. How is it happening internally?

> All Implemented Interfaces: Serializable, Iterable, Collection, Queue.

If it implements comparable, then why doesn't it say in the above line?

Example:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PriorityQueue<String> pq = new PriorityQueue<String>();
        pq.add("2");
        pq.add("4");
        System.out.println(pq); //prints [2, 4]
        pq.offer("1");
        System.out.println(pq); // prints [1, 4, 2]
        pq.add("3");
        System.out.println(pq); // prints [1, 3, 2, 4]
    }
}
```

Also the third print statement prints [1, 3, 2, 4] instead of prints [1, 2, 3, 4]. Why? It should be natural ordering, right?

Comment: The sources are in src.zip.

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/PriorityQueue.java#587

Comment: @JB Nizet: All Implemented Interfaces:
Serializable, Iterable<E>, Collection<E>, Queue<E>

Comment: @JBNizet That's all it implements. I can read it says natural ordering but it doesn't implement comparable if you see this: All Implemented Interfaces: Serializable, Iterable<E>, Collection<E>, Queue<E>

Comment: `E` needs to implement `Comparable` or a `Comparator` needs to be defined, this is clearly stated in the doc. Why should `PriorityQueue` implement `Comparable`?

Comment: @JBNizet You may have missed this part of http://stackoverflow.com/tour

"Remember: we're all here to learn, so be friendly and helpful!"

Even though your answer is helpful, it could be friendlier.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The actual internal data structure of `PriorityQueue` is not ordered. It is a **[heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure))**.

`PriorityQueue` doesn't need to be ordered. Instead, it focuses on **head** of data. Insertion is in *O(log n)* time. Sorting wastes time and is useless for a queue.

Moreover, either the element is-a `Comparable`, or a `Comparator` is provided. Unfortunately, non-comparable checking is at **runtime**, rather than compile time. Once second element is added, `ClassCastException` occurs.

PLUS: My answer to *why [1, 3, 2, 4] instead of prints [1, 2, 3, 4]*?

As I mentioned before, it's not ordered. Instead it focuses on head `q[0]` is minimum; that's it.
You could see the [1, 3, 2, 4] as a tree which is *not* linear:

```
1
| \
3  2
|
4
```

Comment: So elements implement comparable or comparator? I didn't get you

Comment: @kittu: JavaDoc: `A priority queue relying on natural ordering also does not permit
  insertion of non-comparable objects (doing so may result in ClassCastException).`

Comment: wow. thanks a lot. I understood it well with the illustration

Comment: @kittu Hope it helps:) Tree is powerful and interesting data structure.

Comment: If we loop over al the elements we have in an array of size n and then insert them into the priorityQueue, will we have a complexity of n * log n ?

Answer (score 8):

You are seeing that order because:
1. Internally System.out.println() will be invoking the toString() method which in turn uses the iterator to iterate through the elements of the queue. But the iterator does not guarantee any specific order to traverse the elements. Refer this

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

2. Priority queue is based on priority heap. When an element is inserted without any comparator then priority queue uses siftUpComparable() method internally. siftUpComparable() compares the current element with the element at it's parent position in the heap. If the order is not correct then current element and parent element are swapped. This is done until the current element and parent element are in correct order. Ordering is based on natural order of the element. 

3. Since priority queue is based on priority heap its main focus will be on element in front of the queue. 
So the elements are ordered when an element is dequeued from the queue using poll(). This is done to increase the performance of Priority queue. Priority queue only orders the elements when it requires.
If you want to see the order as [1, 2, 3, 4] then use this

```
while(pq.size() != 0) { 
    System.out.println(pq.poll());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The priority queue relies on the following to order the elements:

- Element must be a Comparable type
- Need to provide Comparator implementation for the queue

Answer (score 0):

Actually PriorityQueue allows only those elements which implements Comparable or you need to provide Custom Comparator.

Integer and String values are allowed in Comparator because they implement Comparable interface. e.g.
public final class String  implements java.io.Serializable, Comparable, CharSequence

public final class Integer extends Number implements Comparable

If you create your own class e.g Employee then it should implement Comparable or you should provide your custom Comparator.

I hope this will resolve your queries!!!!