# Comparator not working correctly for Priorityqueue Java

Tags: java, linked-list, comparator, priority-queue

I am adding edges to a PriorityQueue but for some reason they do not get sorted by their value, leading to a faulty result later.

My edge class looks like this

```
class Edge implements Comparable<Edge>{
int value;
String dest;
String start;

public Edge(String start, String dest, int g) {
    this.dest = dest;
    value = g;
    this.start = start;
}
@Override
public int compareTo(Edge o) {
    int temp = value - o.value;
    if (temp > 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (temp < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Yet, when I run my code where I do addAll on a LinkedList belonging to the Node "Springfield, MO" to the PriorityQueue, the Edges get sorted in the wrong order as seen below, what is the issue?

```
queue.addAll(list.get(node));
```

[image]

I have tried to make a specific comparator class for Edge and using it as a parameter in the PriorityQueue but I still get the same result.

Comment: Why do the substraction at all? Why not just `Integer.compare(value, o.value);`?

Comment: I think it's working just fine, given your comparator definition...

Comment: @Neijwiert You are right, however this gives the same result.

Comment: @HBo But why isn't Seminole above Vincennes in the PriorityQueue if the value of it is lower?

Comment: Since you tried @Neijwiert's solution and it didn't pan out, I guess you should try with the given answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The internal structure of the `PriorityQueue` is not ordered, it is a heap, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30072077/priority-queue-ordering-of-elements) question.

When you retrieve data using method `peek` or `poll`, it is guranteed to be ordered.

But be careful when you iterator the queue:

> The Iterator provided in method iterator() is **not guaranteed** to
>   traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order.
>   If you need ordered traversal, consider using
>   Arrays.sort(pq.toArray()).

Comment: Sorry but can you elaborate? Does the iteration in addAll not use the comparator when adding the elements into the PriorityQueue?

Comment: @Slayahh No, the internal structure of the queue is not ordered. It is based on a heap.

Comment: But wouldn't that mean that I have to call sort() every time I added a new element to the queue? Doesn't that diminish the point of a priorityqueue if it doesnt sort the one element that is added?

Comment: @Slayahh You can retrieve element one by one from the queue, you are guranteed to get ordered data.

Comment: Actually, the internal structure of the queue *is* ordered. It's just not *sorted*.

Comment: @Jim Mischel, please clarify. What do you mean when you say the queue is ordered but not sorted.

Comment: @GilbertS The queue is in heap order, which is not necessarily sorted order. For example, the internal order might be `[1,3,2,6,5,4]`. That's in heap order. It's obviously not *sorted*, though.